# Calculate age at 100 in Python, only goes to 99 for odd numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment to use a for loop to display the users age and year and increase by 2 until they user turns 100 or greater. Since the assignment says greater it is ok as it is, only worth 4 pts so no big deal. But I would like to learn how to stop it on 100 if the users age is an odd number such as mine, 57, which goes to 99 or 101.

I've tried several if statements with no luck but I'm a beginner and old!

```
name = input("May I have your name?"" ")
age = int(input("Can I ask how old you are?"" "))
year = 2019

for age in range(age, 101, 2):
  print("In {0} you will be {1} years old, {2}!".format(year, age, name))
  year += 2
```

If there is an easy way to stop it at 100 I would like to understand how, not asking anyone to give me the answer just instructions.

Comment: Keeping on adding 2 to an odd number will never hit 100, what exactly do you want it to do

Comment: Why do you say that it will hit 101? The second argument of `range` is exclusive.

Comment: I can change it to go over to 101 but it will tell the users age at 100 if their age is an odd number. I will probably change it to 101 and be done with it, just wondering if there is a way, not to complicated for a beginner, to make odd numbers show the age at 100 not 101.

Answer (score 3):

#### Boundary check

As mentioned by other answers, the `range()` function with `2` as the third argument will only ever increment the `age` in  multiples of `2`.  It is also exclusive of the last value. If I want to output `100` but the `range()` function only gives me `101`, the most straightforward way is to add a conditional to check for `101` and change it to `100`.

Code example below, stop reading if you want to try it for yourself.

.
..
...

#### Conditional:

```py
  if age == 101:
    age = 100
```

#### Full code:

```py
name = input("May I have your name? ")
age = int(input("Can I ask how old you are? "))
year = 2019

for age in range(age, 102, 2):
  if age == 101:
    age = 100
    year -= 1
  print("In {0} you will be {1} years old, {2}!".format(year, age, name))
  year += 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I was very close today but did a !=100 in my if statement but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The `range` function stops when the number becomes greater or equal to the second parameter. Since you specified this to be `101`, the number will never be 101 or greater.

You're incrementing by 2, so if you start with an odd number all the numbers you generate will be odd. Since you stop when it reaches `101`, the last number generated will be `99`.

You need to decide what actual behavior you want before attempting a fix.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I was satisfied with turning it in as is, 4pts is not going to hurt me, but didn't want there to be a simple change to make it stop at 100.